# Placeholders in Microsoft Word 2013

Tags: ms-word

I'm trying to create something whereby I can enter text once and then display that text back in other places in my document.  What I'm hoping is that if I edit the first instance of the text, the other references of it would update as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with Word "content control databinding"; put both references in a bound content control pointing to the same XML element.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Is the databinding content control something that can only be accessed programmatically, or can it also be accessed somehow via the developer tab in word itself?

Comment: There is http://xmlmapping.codeplex.com/ for 2007/2010; something very similar is baked into Word 2013.